# How do I bundle/include and use files into an executable in C - linux?

Tags: c, linux, file

I've googled this for a bit but I don't seem to get anything resembling what I’m asking.

I'm creating a very simple C script which creates a bunch of template files (none of them are code or libraries or anything, they're just txt files), depending on an argument passed through the console, the way I was gonna resolve this is to just use fopen and fwrite, basically assembling the files line by line, replacing only the ones I need, but I figure there must be a way to bundle some files into the code so I can open and replace just what needs to change from case to case.

I imagine i could also create a couple of const char *file_text and that would do the trick, but I'd like to know if what I'm asking is possible should the need to use something harder to work with than text arise.

Problem is I can't seem to find how, to be clear, I want to do something like this on the console:
./Gen.sh ProjectName

And have Gen.sh be a self-contained file, with no need to keep the original templates around on the same folder.

Comment: Note: There's no such thing as a "C script". C is not a scripting language. It must be compiled or it won't do anything. That being said, why C for this and not something more forgiving like Python, Ruby, Perl, or even Bash?

Comment: You can write a quick build script to convert arbitrary files into C string constants and then compile those into your code, but it's not clear how this would be better than having a directory full of plain files you can easily edit and tune without having to recompile.

Comment: I meant to have it compile into an output through something like this:
gcc -Wall -o Gen.sh -main.c

Comment: Yeah, but because typing all that in is a giant pain when you have to do it repeatedly, usually you'll set up a `Makefile` or something equivalent.

Comment: I was hoping to make it like a portable thing, wich now i think about it doesn't really work in becouse i'd have to recompile it on every pc, guess i could just delete the source once i'm done and have just a single file

Comment: Python is a very popular scripting language and is deployed by default on most Linux distributions since it's used by a lot of system configuration tools. Perl is more old-school but equally ubiquitous. Ruby and Node.js less so, but every one of these is fully portable and requires no recompiling on the part of the user.

Comment: I have a makefile for the script, though the code is so simple that the end result is basically this: gcc -Wall -o Gen.sh -main.c

Comment: I was hoping to do it with C becouse it's the only thing I can code with right now, the whole purpose was to use this generator to create simple "projects" to learn C++

Comment: `xxd -i somefile` outputs C code that represents the contents of the file as an unsigned char array.

Comment: Just a note: files ending with `.sh` are usually reserved for shell scripts; see the Life cycle section in this Wikipedia section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script#Life_cycle.

Comment: If you already know your way around C or C++ then figuring out Python won't be hard, but if you do want to try this in C++ you're going to have to wrestle with making a distribution package or `Configure` script of some kind so people can actually use it. In the old days, back when computers had spinning tapes on them, people would make a "self-compiling" shell-script with C code in it, but those proved to be very difficult to maintain and also a bit scary to use.

Comment: I wound up going with the xxd -i somefile solution, it did the job fine but the checked answer is more what I was going for, I've left a public repo in my response to that with the way this turned out in case someone is interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [linker to do such embedding](https://csl.name/post/embedding-binary-data/)

```
$ ld -r -b binary cat.png -o cat.o
```

> The object file will have three symbols in it,

```
$ nm cat.o
_cat_start
_cat_end
_cat_size
```

> To use them from C, declare some `extern` variables

```
extern const char cat_start;
extern const char cat_end;
extern const int cat_size;
```

Then you can link the generated object file ,the same can be used for text files

Comment: This will include the file content in the process' memory space. It's convenient to access it. But if you have dozens of files your process foot print increases. Do you know a way to map just one specific file to the progress on demand?

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted to do; I'll have to try this later, as I used one of the above suggestions to hack my way around the problem, though I don't think the code would be that much different from what it has turned out to be.

In case someone wants to check the "solution": https://github.com/CrainFartor/CPPTemplatleProjectFileGenerator

Comment: @harper you can always have either compressed data, or use dynamic libraries (which kind of defeat the purpose )

Comment: In the case of dynamic data I have all files (compressed) in the process memory, additionally I need a library to decompress it.

Comment: @harper it really depend what your target is, and your constraints are, but you would have to choose some compromise if you want to "bundle the file with the executable". Otherwise just put your files into a .zip or a .tar archive beside your executable